# how to update native existing apps to flutter in Appstore and PlayStore?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I already have an existing native app on AppStore and play store which builds in swift and java respectively. now I want to make my ios and android app in one code base so I choose flutter and build my app in a flutter.
but the problem is how I can give updates in Appstore and play store in existing apps I don't want to lose my users by uploading new apps separately. so what is the best way I can migrate my projects with flutter without losing existing users?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge pay store tracks your app by signing key of the app which you have added and uploaded to the play store for your old app, which is built with native language, same as updating your old app in the play store you can update the whole app by the new framework. Make sure the new flutter version app has the same key which you have used in the old app.

it's just my understanding.